# Crystal Report Insert Sum Grand Total based on formula

Tags: loops, crystal-reports, formula

I am new to crystal report. I do have a monthly report to compute the sum of output done by our workers.

I created three formula to compute the Sum of our workers monthly output.

//Formula A

```
WhileReadingRecords;

NumberVar manualTotal :=0;
//I place this in my Report Header
```

//Formula B

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

NumberVar manualTotal := manualTotal + {@SubTotalQty};
//I place this in my Group Header
```

//Formula C

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar manualTotal;
manualTotal
//I place this in my Group Footer
```

The output of our first worker is correct but the second one goes wrong because it keeps on adding the manualTotal of previous worker. Is there a way to stop the looping?

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: what are your groupings?

Answer (score 0):

Change like this.....

//Formula A

```
WhileReadingRecords;

NumberVar manualTotal :=0;
//I place this in my Group Header
```

//Formula B

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

NumberVar manualTotal := manualTotal + {@SubTotalQty};
manualTotal 
//I place this in my Group Footer
```